# OpenMDAO: interrupt a design of experiment computations

Tags: openmdao

I am creating this new topic because I am using the OpenMDAO platform, and more specifically its design of experiment option. I would like to know if there is a proper way to interrupt and stop the computations if a condition is met in my program.

I have already used OpenMDAO optimizers to study and solve some problems and to stop the computations I used to raise an Exception to stop the program. This strategy seems to work for optimizers but not so much when I am using the LatinHypercubeGenerator driver: it is like the OpenMDAO program is still trying to compute the points even if Exception or RuntimeError are raise within the OpenMDAO explicit component function "compute".

In that respect I am wondering if there is a way to kill OpenMDAO during calculations. I tried to check if an OpenMDAO built-in attribute or method could do the job, but I have not found anything.

Does anyone know how to stop OpenMDAO DOE computations?
Many thanks in advance for any advice/help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of OpenMDAO V3.18, there is no way to add some kind off a stopping condition to the DOE driver. You mention using AnalysisError to achieve this for other optimizers. This won't work in general either, since some drivers will intentionally catch those errors, react, and attempt to keep running the optimization.

You can see the run code of the driver, where a for loop is made and some [try/catch blocks](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/3.18.0/openmdao/drivers/doe_driver.py#L184-L211) are used to record the success/failure of specific cases.

My suggestion for achieving what you want would be to copy the driver code into your model directory and make your own custom drivers. You can add whatever kind of termination condition you like, either based on results of a single case or some statistical analysis of the currently run cases.

If you come up with a clean way of doing it, you can always submit a [POEM](https://github.com/openmdao/poems) and/or a pull request to propose adding your new functionality to the mainline of OpenMDAO.

Comment: And if I am using a thread or a process to perform my DOE, do you know if there is way to terminate the process from the inside? I know that it is possible to terminate a process by calling the built-in method terminate() but this has to be done outside the process. Do you know if something similar could be done but from the inside of the process?

Comment: this sounds like a separate question to me. I suggest you make a very simple example case and post a separate question. I realize its related to the issue of stopping via analysis error, but it foundationally deals more with multi threading, and in that context I think its a different question all together.

Comment: I found the solution to my problem: I am using a process to launch the computations, then by using the command os.kill(os.getpid(), 0) I can kill the process. Thanks for your help :)